# Adding html class according to xslt statement

Tags: xslt

xslt is pretty new for me. Is it possible to do something similar to my code below. I know it is possible in other template languages.

```
  <div class="<xsl:if test="position()=1">myclass</xsl:if>">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could wrap an `xsl:attribute` in an `xsl:if`...

```
    <div>
        <xsl:if test="position()=1">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">myclass</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:text>Hello</xsl:text>
    </div>
```

Also, in XSLT 2.0, you can write the `xsl:attribute` like this:

```
<xsl:attribute name="class" select="'myClass'"/>
```

Another XSLT 2.0 option, if you don't mind having an empty `class=""`, is to use an `if` in an AVT ([Attribute Value Template](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-20/#attribute-value-templates)):

```
<div class="{if (position()=1) then . else ''}">...</div>
```

The `then` may vary depending on context.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this:

```
<xsl:variable name="myclass" select="variablenode" />
    
<div class="adf">
<xsl:if test="yournode[position()=1]">
    <xsl:value-of select="$myclass"/>
</xsl:if>
Hello</div>
```

But please give us your source XML, the XSLT you have so far and the expected output. Otherwise we can only guess.